# Is there a way to implement "join table" in has_many_through , instead of creating a seperate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create a has_many_through relationships, by creating two model named as subjects and lesssons. I need to create a join table instead of creating a seperate model.Expecting a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: share what you have done so far

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The [`has_and_belongs_to_many` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) is a many to many association without a join model:

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lessons
end

class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
end
```

To generate the join table run `rails g CreateJoinTableLessonsSubjects lessons subjects`:

```
class CreateJoinTableLessonsSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :lessons, :subjects do |t|
      # t.index [:lesson_id, :subject_id]
      # t.index [:subject_id, :lesson_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the table naming is different `lessons_subjects` compared to  `lesson_subjects` for `has_many through:`.

While `has_and_belongs_to_many` is somewhat simpler and saves memory by not instantiating join model instances there are some big drawbacks:

- No good way to query the join table directly.
- No way to access additional columns on the join table that describes the relation between A & B.

You can quite simply go from `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many through:` at a later point if you find that you need those features by just renaming the table and creating a join model.

Comment: Actually, I need to create a join table along with has_many, not has_and_belongs_to_many. Is there any solution?

Comment: has_many through: uses a join table as well. The difference is that has_many though uses a model to represent rows in the join table. So no there is no solution - learn the framework instead.